# error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of �serivces� with no type [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, irc

Okay I'm an noob at this, but I think I got all this set up correctly, and I am being thown an:

```
[Admin@shadowrealm ircservices]$ g++ main.cpp -o services
In file included from main.cpp:1:0:
services.h:8:15: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of âserivcesâ with no type [-fpermissive]
```

by the compiler (using g++)

main.cpp:

```
#include "services.h"

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int ac, char **av)
{
    services myservices;

    if(myservices.startup() == 1)
         cout << "Cool this works!!" << endl;

        return(0);
}
```

services.h:

```
#ifndef SERVICES_H
#define SERVICES_H

class services
{

public:
     serivces();
     ~services();
     int startup();
};

#endif
```

services.cpp:

```
#include "services.h"

services::services()
{
}

services::~services()
{
}

int services::startup()
{
return 1;
}
```

this is puzzling to me, but as i said im not a pro at this, so watch it be some obvious error like "change 1 to 2" or something...

Comment: Typo: `serivces();` -> `services();`

Comment: that did fix the issue, but another arose, but i fixed it, which leads me to another question the second error was fixed due to changing in main.cpp services.h to services.cpp - anyone know why?

Comment: If you have another issue after fixing this one, it is better to post a different question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm replying to your second improvement.

You were probably missing one compilation step which is the creation of the `object` file:

First step:

```
g++ -c services.cpp
```

This will create the object file that you can use for the last step which is called linking:

```
g++ main.cpp services.cpp -o executablename
```

Including the `.cpp` files in the main solves the problem because you where literally pasting the entire code inside the main during pre-processing.

I suggest to read this http://homepages.gac.edu/~mc38/2001J/documentation/g++.html as an introduction to g++ compilation steps and this 
[wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) to get introduced to the ELF file format.